# Trying to implement a CNN+LSTM for fight detection - Some issues with the architecture

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, lstm

I'm working on a fight detector. Few days ago I found an interesting paper implementing a CNN+LSTM with quite good results for violence detection.
I would like to implement their model. Here is the link of the paper : [https://deliverypdf.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=800100124064071090094085000072099081004046034042033020101112001046029090119009111067089105058063117076066014069065030066046089004054024119011123014127038008100035006073050072075023078053028013051068001021010069094127065108022101092007071093118073029027118095127091066124008066010125068&EXT=pdf&INDEX=TRUE](https://stackoverflow.com)

So I tried to implement their model with keras by following the architectute (page 4-5) but I have so much parameters for my CNN.
Here is my code for implementing the model :

```
model = Sequential()

# Add a TimeDistributed layer wrapping each Conv2D layer
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'), input_shape=(24, 90, 160, 3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same')))

# Add a TimeDistributed Flatten layer
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

# Add a TimeDistributed Dense layer
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(512)))

# Add a GRU layer
model.add(GRU(64))

# Add additional Dense and Dropout layers
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

And this is the summary with the number of parameters. I have 61M whereas they only have 3M. What's wrong with my code ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu7ek.png)

Thank's in advance for your help !

Comment: Remove layers and/ or reduce the units of your existing layers.

Comment: ok thanks but do you know why I don't have the same number of parameters as them ? It seems to be the same model no ?

Comment: No need to be condescending. I'm trying to help you, and I'm telling you the exact issue. Please, enlighten me on how a model with the 'exact' same configuration could have different parameter numbers? That's right, it can't.

Therefore, the problem has to be with your implementation, likely being the layers and/ or different units in the layers.